# GNU make rule for multiple targets

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to get GNU make to produce multiple outputs from a single input. The most simple example I can demonstrate is:

```
a b : test
    cp $< $@
```

which, I believe, should copy the file `test` to the files name `a` and `b`. However, it only makes the file `a`, which seems to me to be contrary to the instructions listed here:

http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/make/Multiple-Targets.html

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 9):

If you run a rule that depends on `a`, it will run your rule with `$<` as `test` and `$@` as `a`. If you run a rule that depends on `b`, `$@` will be `b` instead. If you make a rule above your current rule like:

```
all: a b
```

It will run the rules for `a` and `b`, which is that same rule twice. Otherwise, if your rule is the first in the file it will run it with the first target only, which is `a`

Answer (score 0):

A small clarification to @MichaelMrozek's answer.

This:

```
a b : test
    cp $< $@
```

Is exactly the same as:

```
a : test
    cp $< $@
b : test
    cp $< $@
```

*a* is the first target in the file, so it's the default target.  Only the rule for *a* runs, since there's no dependency on *b*.

Like @MichaelMrozek said, you can add another rule, or you can run

```
make a b
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is OK. The manual says :

```
bigoutput littleoutput : text.g
        generate text.g -$(subst output,,$@) > $@
```

is equivalent to

```
bigoutput : text.g
        generate text.g -big > bigoutput
littleoutput : text.g
  generate text.g -little > littleoutput
```

So your Makefile is also equivalent to

```
a : test
    cp $< $@
b : test
    cp $< $@
```

and when you'd entered the command 'make', the program defaulted to build the first target, i.e. 'a'.